# Rails uniqueness validation with nested has_many

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am building a Polls website and I want to achieve that a user (ip address) can vote once per poll. I have the following models:

```
class Poll < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :answers, :dependent => :destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :answers, allow_destroy: true
end

class Answer < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :poll
  has_many :votes
end

class Vote < ApplicationRecord
  validates_uniqueness_of :ip_address
  belongs_to :answer
end
```

With my current solution a user can vote once on one poll and then he can't vote on another.
What should I use to `validates_uniqueness_of :ip_address` per poll? 
I tried to use scope by poll but it didn't work.

PS: I know IP address is not the best solution for validating unique votes.

Comment: Just use a cookie instead and handle it on the controller level. If you use an ip based solution you can end up blocking all users of an ISP or univerisity or whatever that share a common public ip. Yeah cookies are flawed - but much less so.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need scoped uniqueness

```
validates :ip_address, uniqueness: { scope: :answer_id }
```

It will not allow a duplicate `ip_address` per `answer`

https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#uniqueness

You can also enforce it at database level by adding this to migration, this is optional though

```
add_index :votes, [:ip_address, :answer_id], unique: true
```

But the above solution will only keep user from not voting for an answer more than once. If you want uniqueness with `poll`, one option is to save `poll_id` in `answers` table as well and then define uniqueness on that,

or, second option is to define custom validation in `Vote` model

```
validate :uniqueness_with_poll

def uniqueness_with_poll
  errors.add(:answer_id, 'already voted for poll') if answer_for_poll_exists?
end

def answer_for_poll_exists?
  answer_voted = Vote.where(ip_address: ip_address).pluck(:answer_id)
  return false if answer_voted.blank?

  answer.poll.answers.where(id: answer_voted).exists?
end
```

Then defining a method `answer_for_poll_exists?` to check whether poll is already voted, but this could be costly though.

Hope that helps!

Comment: I am using the Second option with custom validation. When voting for the second time I get the error "undefined method `vote' for #<Answer id: 3, content: "text", poll_id: 1> Did you mean? votes". There is a problem in the line answer.vote.answers.where(id: answer_voted).exists?

Comment: @MatiasJurfest Sorry, I edited my answer, it should be `answer.poll.answers`